# ContactsContract.Data._ID value is always the same

Tags: android

I am querying a user profile data on an Android Phone using the following URI:

```
Uri.withAppendedPath(Profile.CONTENT_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

All ContactsContract.Data rows seem to be returned correctly (structured names, phones,email, web, etc).  The problem I am having is that

```
curData.getLong(curData.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
```

returns the same value for every row, even though other columns have different values.  Could somebody help me understand why is this happening?  How can I distinguish one ContactsContract.Data row from another?

Comment: Just verified that the returned ContactsContract.Data._ID value is the same as ContactsContract.Contacts._ID of the parent contact.  Very strange, probably an Android bug related to querying contact data through Entity URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that  [Entity.DATA_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.html#DATA_ID) should be used instead of ContactsContract.Data._ID when querying ContactsContract.Data rows through Entity URIs.